# Problema na hora de fazer push no GitHub

Tags: git, github

Opa, estou tentando enviar meus arquivos para um repositorio no github mas tá dando erro. 
Fiz da seguinte forma:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "xxx"
git remote add origin https://github.com/rodriguesJeff/classes_dbv/
git push origin master
```

Mas tá dando o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Daí eu dou o git pull e dá isso:

```
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Ajuda aí pls

Comment: Evite postar mensagem de erro como imagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só rodar os seguintes comandos e depois dar o push de novo

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, funcionou

Answer (score 3):

Isso ocorre quando a sua versão local (na sua máquina) está "atrasada" em relação a sua versão remota (no seu caso, que está no GitHub). Imagina o seguinte cenário:

1. Você cria um arquivo `teste.html` com o conteúdo abaixo e faz o `commit` e `push` para salvar no GitHub

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Helo World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Helo World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Seu colega de trabalho que não tem nada pra fazer (ou até você mesmo em outra máquina) olha esse arquivo e muda os textos, traduzindo para português. Novamente é salvo no GitHub
3. No outro dia você quer fazer um teste de animação com o título na página, você commita mas quando tentar salvar no GitHub, da esse erro

A solução é fazer o `pull` primeiro para sincronizar o local com o remoto e então salvar, mas tome cuidado, dependendo da situação pode ser que alguma alteração de conflito, se estiver usando uma IDE boa ela irá lhe alertar

Em algumas situações talvez você queira escrever o código local em cima do remoto, eu faço bastante isso, as vezes eu esqueço de commitar algum arquivo e volto para o commit anterior, recommito (dessa vez com o arquivo que faltou) e fasso `push` usando a opção `--force`